# Cloudera Impala from c# CDH5

Tags: c#, odbc, impala

how to use the Cloudera ODBC Imapala driver from c# to execute SQL statement

Driver works when used from excel or access

but error in code :-

```
        var conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala};Server=192.168.220.3;PORT=21050;DSN=impala";
        conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your driver in ODBC data Source (Control Panel -> select System and Security -> Administrative Tools). Try to configure it completely (host, ip, auth, ..) there and click on "Test". If it's okay, just try :

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Sample Cloudera Impala DSN");
DbConnection.Open();
```

If this works, you can add Server=192.168.220.3;PORT=21050 to this connection string.